# What are Rimuru's power in the manga or web novel?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

I kinda remember someone saying that Rimuru can make a whole planet and life forms on it.  Can anyone check this and if true what chapter in the manga or web novel?

Answer (score 1):

**SlimeViscous** Organism: As a Slime, Rimuru is a monster that doesn't need to breathe, sleep or eat, as he can survive only on the magicules in the atmosphere.

**Intrinsic Skills**: As a Slime, Rimuru has the species-specific Skills of Absorb, Dissolve, and Self-Regeneration. These are later fused into Unique Skill Predator to create Extra Skill Ultraspeed Regeneration.

1. **Absorb and Dissolve**: Slime-species intrinsic Skills that are inferior versions of Unique Skills Predator and Glutton.
2. **Self-Regeneration**: Allows the user to regenerate from injuries which include regenerating lost limbs. An inferior version of Extra
   Skill Ultraspeed Regeneration.

**Demon SlimeDemonic Viscous Spirit Body**: As a Demon Slime all his bodily attributes are greatly enhanced. He can freely change between a material and a spiritual body.

**Intrinsic skills**: As a Demon Slime, Rimuru has the species-specific skills of Infinite Regeneration, Control Magic, Multilayer Barrier, Universal Detect, Universal Shapeshift, Demon Lord’s Haki, Enhanced Replication, Spatial Motion, Darkflame Lightning, and Universal Thread.

1. **Infinite Regeneration**: Enhanced version of Extra Skill Ultraspeed Regeneration. Works even quicker than its previous
   version and can now even regenerate from having the Spiritual Body
   shattered.
2. **Control Magic**: Same as its Extra Skill version, but further enhanced.
3. **Multilayer Barrier**: Same as its Extra Skill version, but further enhanced.
4. **Universal Detect**: Multi-purpose Sense-Skill that contains the effects of other Sense-Skills like Magic Sense, Sense Heat Source,
5. **Sense Soundwave, and Keen Smell.**
6. **Universal Shapeshift**: Same as its Extra Skill version, but further enhanced.
7. **Demon Lord's Haki**: A Skill that enhances a magic-based creature's Monster Aura. Needs to be at least on the level of a
   Demon Lord Breed to acquire. This Skill is a composite of several
   other Skills like Coercion and Magic Aura, among others. It causes
   Fear and can even cause instant death to those who can't resist it.
8. **Enhanced Replication Improved version of Replication**. Capable of being used as an incarnation medium for True Dragons.
9. **Spatial Motion**: Same as its Extra Skill version, but further enhanced.
10. **Darkflame Lightning**: Enhanced version of combined Extra Skills Dark Flame and Dark Thunder.
11. **Universal Thread**: Enhanced version of Sticky-Steel Thread.

**These are just physical aspects, there are far more powers than I can list, check out the wiki**

source: https://tensura.fandom.com/wiki/Rimuru_Tempest/Abilities_and_Gears